# How to get decimal value having zero from reader in C#

Tags: c#, decimal

How could I define precision and scale for decimal.I need to get decimal value including the zeros in after the decimal point.

ex:store proc returns numeric 50.00 but while assigning that value to decimal it is truncating as 50.I want whole 50.00 to be assigned to variable.

Comment: Are you actually converting to `decimal`, or to `double`? Could you show your code? What's the type in your database?

Comment: Do you actually need to know the difference between `50.0` and `50.00`?  `decimal` and `double` don't do this.

Comment: @TimS.: `double` doesn't, but `decimal` does.

Comment: Datatype in stored proc or db is numeric(10,2) and when I retrieve data using data reader it's been converted to decimal.

decimal SampleValue = reader.GetDecimal(OrdSamplevalue);